# how to mock AggregateResult Object in APEX

Tags: apex

I want to test the AggregateResult in my class.

if the result of AggregateResult instance is greater than 0 then controller enter the loop.
How should i mock the AggregateResult object in my test class.

```
AggregateResult[] ar = [select AccountID,count(abc__c) policy_number, sum(Amount) amount from case where accountid = :a.id  group by AccountID];
```

All I need is how to mock ar in my test class with out hitting database.

Comment: See [Is there a way I can mock an AggregateResult?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173193/is-there-a-way-i-can-mock-an-aggregateresult) for one idea and some comments. If you mock this, you will not be testing the behaviour of the query which is a key part of the logic. I suggest instead that you insert test data and run the real query.