# SOQL aggregate statement using FFLIB

Tags: fflib

Please, It is possible to write a SOQL aggregate statement  using fflib_SObjectSelector?
For example, I have this SOQL request:
**SELECT  DX_Support__r.Name support, SUM(total__c) total FROM DX_Turnover__c GROUP BY DX_Support__r.Name LIMIT 10.**

I use FFLIB framework in my project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that it is an SObject selector, I'd say not. Take a look at [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_selector_l_principles) for some discussion over selectors (where it mentions aggregate query solutions).

Comment: Thanks @PhilW for this link. Unfortunately, I hadn't seen nothing about the SOQL aggregate Statement. I just need to transform this SOQL request above using FFLib (Selector layer).

Comment: What I'm saying is that you might need to write your own selector that doesn't implement the fflib_ISObjectSelector interface/fflib_SObjectSelector class.

Comment: Ah Okay! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this depends on whether you want to mock the response using ApexMocks or some other dependency injection scheme

### No mocking of response required

Within your selector class

```
public virtual AggregateResult[] selectTurnoverGroupedByName(..) {
 
    return [SELECT DX_Support__r.Name support, SUM(total__c) total 
             FROM DX_Turnover__c GROUP BY DX_Support__r.Name LIMIT 10
}
```

That is, the selector class includes a normal Aggregate Query SOQL without using any of the fflib_QueryFactory methods as those don't support aggregate queries.

### Mocking of Response required

If using ApexMocks or other dependency injection, Apex doesn't permit mocking `AggregateResult`, even if you use the JSON serialize/deserialize approach.  So, your selector method is going to have to return a Proxy object that models `AggregateResult` as a `Map<String,Object>`. There's a [Q&A on approaches to do this in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173193/is-there-a-way-i-can-mock-an-aggregateresult/273697#273697)